# How do you open the command line tool in the Dart Editor?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

The one that you use to write things as "pub install" and such.

Comment: Is there one? I did that always in the specific directory with a simple command bash from the OS. AFAIK the editor had somewhere a check box or a button for "pub install".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Dart Editor does not provide an integrated shell.  You'll have to open whatever shell is available on your system, or install one of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for pub integration, you can find `pub install` and `pub update` from the Tools menu.