# How do you access the command line in Dart Pub package manager

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

I am trying to explore using Dart's Pub package manager on the command line.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this, and all the documentation I have read, presupposes that this is known.  What are the actual steps needed to set up the command line, so you can run pub commands on GNU/Linux systems?

This is an expansion on this question:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529556/how-do-you-open-the-command-line-tool-in-the-dart-editor).  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Linux and you've unpackaged the SDK in /home/$USER/ you should add the SDK PATH to the bottom of your `.bashrc`.

`vim ~/.bashrc`

```
 DART_SDK=/home/${USER}/dart/dart-sdk
 export PATH=${PATH}:${DART_SDK}/bin
 alias DartEditor='/home/${USER}/dart/DartEditor'
 alias dartium='/home/${USER}/dart/chromium/chrome'
```

You might have to run `source ~/.bashrc` to have the binaries available in your current console.

Now you should be able to run `pub --help` and work your way from there. Also you can now open the editor and the dart based chrome from the commandline like this: `DartEditor` or `dartium` (add `& exit` to those command if you don't want the output from those programs).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you.  That worked perfectly.  For future users, type in the text exactly, editing only the location of the files.  Do NOT replace ${USER} for your user name, and do not change the text ${PATH} or ${DART_SDK} either.  I thought I was supposed to replace these with the my own user name, or the actual path, but just type those in exactly as Andreas wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add the dart-sdk/bin directory to the path or create symlinks in /usr/bin for the command line tools you want to have available. You can of course just use the full path to the executables.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  I am in the folder /home/user/dart/dark-sdk/bin/.  What am I supposed to type?  Thanks for your time.